# SWIG error: Syntax Error in input(1)

Tags: c, swig

I'm getting the  Syntax Error in input(1) error for this line of code, in C when I do:

swig -python myfile.i in console.

It concerns the following code, specifically the last line of these typedefs.

```
typedef unsigned short WORD;    
typedef unsigned int DWORD;
typedef unsigned long long QWORD;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;     
typedef unsigned int bool; //<= THIS LINE OF CODE TRIGGERS THE ERROR.
```

As far as I know, bool is not defined in C so I would think swig would let this go with no issue. I compiled as c in VS 2010 and it was just fine.

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C does have a `bool` type (actually a macro) but it is a C99 feature and you have to include `stdbool.h` to get `bool`; you only have `_Bool` if you don't include `stdbool.h`.

VS2010 doesn't support C99, it only supports C89 (AFAIK) so the `typedef` will work fine with that.

I'd guess that something somewhere is pulling in `stdbool.h` and that is messing up your `typedef` as it will look like this:

```
typedef unsigned int _Bool;
```

when the compiler sees it and the compiler won't like that at all.

Comment: What do you think GCC / swig will see it as? I don't have stdbool.h included anywhere explicitly. 

I've got

    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

included. Do any of those include stdbool?

Comment: @limenuke: I don't who is pulling in `stdbool.h`. Try a simple "hello world" program that uses those headers and includes your `typedef unsigned int bool;`. Maybe swig is pulling it in somewhere.

Comment: I found I've no need to use the lowercase bool and will be using BOOL (which I've tested and works). Either way, I couldn't get to test out your method. Thanks anyways!